# Consuming multiple csv files describing a nested structure in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I have a requirement to consume a csv "dataset" consisting of 3 flat files - a control file, a headers file, and a line file - which together define a nested data structure.

The control file items have a field called ControlID, which can be used in the headers file to identify those header records which "belong" to that control item.

The header records have a field called HeaderID, which can be used in the lines file to identify those line records which "belong" to a given header record.

I'd like to consume all three files and then map them into some kind of nested schema structure. My question is how would I do this? Can I do it in a pipeline component?

Comment: Very important question, is there a way to directly correlate the files to each other?  Like a key in the file name or header record?

Comment: @Johns-305 - yes there is. So we have a way of identifying a discreet "set" of files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at two options.  Both involve correlation all three files to an Orchestration using a [Parallel Convoy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/parallel-convoys).

1. Use a Multi-input Map to join the files.  You should be able to use the HeaderID as filter using the Equal Function to match the lines to their header.
2. Use a SQL Stored Procedure to group the data as described here: [BizTalk: Sorting and Grouping Flat File Data In SQL Instead of XSL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51155.biztalk-sorting-and-grouping-flat-file-data-in-sql-instead-of-xsl.aspx)

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. So your option 1 is to consume the files according to their own flat file schemas, and then use a map to join them. Actually this would be preferable to loading them into SQL and then doing some shaping using FOR XML. Could you elaborate on *You should be able to use the HeaderID as filter using the Equal Function to match the lines to their header* if it's not too much to ask? Thanks

Comment: @tomredfern  Check out the article.  You don't need any tables or anything other than the Stored Procedure.